# How to have a parent check box that controls child checkbox UWP c#

Tags: c#, checkbox, uwp

I have this in my uwp program:

[image]

I want it so that:

- If the parent check box is checked all children are too.
- If the parent check box is unchecked all children are too.
- If all the children check boxes are checked the parent will also check.
- If any of the children check boxes are not checked then the parent wont be checked.

My current code can handle the first three however when I un-check one of the children the unchecked operation for the parent is activated and this un-checks all the children.

The check boxes are bounded to bool items of the same name.

Checked Code:

```
private void IsChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox checkBox = sender as CheckBox;

    if (checkBox.Name == "chkWeekday")
    {
        Monday = true;
        Tuesday = true;
        Wednesday = true;
        Thursday = true;
        Friday = true;
    }
    else
    {
        switch (checkBox.Name) // Handles data not updating yet
        {
            case "chkMonday":
                Monday = true;
                break;
            case "chkTuesday":
                Tuesday = true;
                break;
            case "chkWednesday":
                Wednesday = true;
                break;
            case "chkThursday":
                Thursday = true;
                break;
            case "chkFriday":
                Friday = true;
                break;
        }
        if (Monday && Tuesday && Wednesday && Thursday && Friday)
        {
            Weekday = true;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Un-check Code:

```
private void IsUnchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox checkBox = sender as CheckBox;

    if (checkBox.Name == "chkWeekday")
    {
        Monday = false;
        Tuesday = false;
        Wednesday = false;
        Thursday = false;
        Friday = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Weekday = false; //<============================================ This is why it un-checks all
        switch (checkBox.Name) // Handles data not updating yet
        {
            case "chkMonday":
                Monday = false;
                break;
            case "chkTuesday":
                Tuesday = false;
                break;
            case "chkWednesday":
                Wednesday = false;
                break;
            case "chkThursday":
                Thursday = false;
                break;
            case "chkFriday":
                Friday = false;
                break;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this more efficiently / in a way that work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It‘s better not to subscribe to Checked and Unchecked events, when you set the IsChecked property, it always triggers the two events, it would be inconvenient to judge. In this scenario, you could just subscribe the Click event for your CheckBoxs. For example:

```
private void MyCheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox checkBox = sender as CheckBox;

    if (checkBox.Name == "chkWeekday" && checkBox.IsChecked == true)// First demand
    {
        chkTuesday.IsChecked = chkWednesday.IsChecked = chkThursday.IsChecked = true;
    }
    else if (checkBox.Name == "chkWeekday" && checkBox.IsChecked == false) // Second demand
    {
        chkTuesday.IsChecked = chkWednesday.IsChecked = chkThursday.IsChecked = false;
    }
    else if (chkTuesday.IsChecked == true && chkWednesday.IsChecked == true && chkThursday.IsChecked == true) //Third demand
    {
        chkWeekday.IsChecked = true;
    }
    else //Fourth demand
    {
        chkWeekday.IsChecked = false;
    }
}
```